# Record from Gridview not deleting

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception, delete-row, aspxgridview

I am trying to delete a record from my Gridview and I get a InvalidCastException with the message "Conversion from string "RefYear" to type 'Integer' is not valid." I am also using Data Keys.

Gridview Code section for column in question

```
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ref. Year" SortExpression="ReferenceYear" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RefYear") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RefYear") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnInsertRecord" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert Record"
                                        ValidationGroup="Insert" CssClass="buttonBlue" />
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Code Behind

```
Protected Friend Sub dgvBusinessCompetitions_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles dgvBusinessCompetitions.RowDeleting

    ' Read the keys from data keys
    Dim _rewardDescription As String = dgvBusinessCompetitions.DataKeys(e.RowIndex)("RewardDescription")
    Dim _referenceYear As Integer = dgvBusinessCompetitions.DataKeyNames(1)

    Company.Applications.ProductionEngine.BusinessAccess.BusinessCompetitionBusinessAccess.DeleteBusinessCompetitionReward(_rewardDescription,
                                                                                                                            _referenceYear,
                                                                                                                            _groupType)

    InformationBox.ShowSuccessMessage("Record deleted successfully.")
    loadBusinessCompetitionsConditions()
End Sub
```

Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_procedure] 

    @rewardDescription VARCHAR(100),
    @groupType VARCHAR (50),
    @refYear INT 
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM myTable
    WHERE RewardDescription = @rewardDescription
    AND GroupType = @groupType
    AND RefYear = @refYear
END
```

What I need to be done, is upon clicking delete, I need the particular record with X reward description, X Group type and X RefYear to be deleted as the stored procedure displays.

I've tried converting RefYear but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed

```
Dim _referenceYear As Integer = dgvBusinessCompetitions.DataKeyNames(1)
```

To

```
Dim _referenceYear As Integer = dgvBusinessCompetitions.DataKeys(e.RowIndex)("RefYear")
```